# An adjective for "doubt" when it is not reasonable?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Some people raised serious doubts as to the value of the research on
> global warming. But such doubts **are** ------ .
>
> Some people raised serious doubts as to the value of the research on
> global warming. But such doubts **are not** ------ .

I can think of "im/plausible", "ir/rational", "un/reasonable", and "un/justified". And I can see each of these being used here or there online. But I would like to know what is the most idiomatic adjective when we want to say a doubt is not reasonable or appropriate.

Comment: "injustified" is not a word. "justified" take the prefix "un". You may be confusing it with "justice", which does take the "in" prefix. One of the confusing things about English is that words can take different prefixes even if the have the same root, such as "uncivil" versus "incivility".

Comment: Are you truly asking for an idiom? I can think of several words that work, but are not idioms.

Comment: @user22542 I am looking for an adjective for "doubt", whether an idiom or not.

Answer (score 3):

"Implausible", "irrational", "unreasonable" and "unjustified" are all used with approximately equal frequency as is "inappropriate". Which of those you use depends very much on the context, the strength of the evidence you are presenting and the effect you are trying to create. As you have indicated that you consider the doubt is "not reasonable" I would use "unreasonable" but give your grounds for that holding that opinion to protect yourself against the wrath of the climate change deniers.

Answer (score 2):

Another adjective frequently used to dismiss doubts is **unwarranted**.

> Their doubts were unwarranted.

But you could also say that they're **ignorant** or **founded in ignorance**.

> The president's frequent expression of doubt about global warming as he points to cold snaps and blizzards is **founded in ignorance**.

Comment: "unwarranted" meaning "not supported by evidence"?

Comment: The meaning is a little broader than that ("lacking a good reason, lacking justification") which would certainly encompass "not justified *by evidence*".

Answer (score 0):

my contributions are "**groundless**" and "**unfounded**" or something similar as the case may require (i.e. **ungrounded, baseless, substantiated/unsubstantiated** etc.). Possibly they are more idiomatic.

And...one more that might work is "**unsound**".

> Some people raised serious doubts as to the value of the research on
>   global warming. But such doubts are **unfounded** .
>
> Some people raised serious doubts as to the value of the research on
>   global warming. But such doubts are **groundless**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfounded

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/groundless

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/baseless

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/substantiated

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsound